# How to connect snappy-data to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, snappydata

Hi I am start to learn snappy-data documentation version 0.7 for the purpose of connect to the snappy-data with Apache hadoop, i am following this documenation [link](http://rowstore.docs.snappydata.io/docs/disk_storage/persist-hdfs-topics.html#topic_v5l_3nn_ml) but this documentation is not much clear how to configure snappy row store to hdfs, i can't able to fetch the correct solution on it, if any one know how to configure snappy-data rowstore to hdfs please share me ,Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? Please paste your code. What exactly does not work

Comment: When i execute the query **select * from table ** the snappy-data will store the snappy table , if the snappy-data table will get overflow means my data will store on hdfs table, in this scenario i need to configure snappy-data row store with hdfs, but as per the mentioned link they not specified where we to configure which location either hdfs or snappy-data,i don't understand the configuration  please guide me if you know the correct configuration Thank you.